# "React native run-android" giving connection time out

Tags: android, react-native

I did all the setup as mentioned in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html#content page.

I'm under Windows, trying to use genymotion.

When i run "React native run-android"  it is giving an exception :

`java.net.ConnectException`

[here is snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnYwB.png)

Would you have any idea to explain that, did I miss something ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your code needs to be corrected or explained. See the **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 5):

I found out the solution,Problem was with proxy server.
As android uses grandle for building project, i had to set proxy server in grandle property file

I just set the following in gradle.properties in the android folder

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyHost

systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxyPort

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyHost

systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxyPort
```